# spider set as default in a scrapy project

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have a scrapy project with two spiders. spider_a and spider_b.

The problem I'm facing is that spider_b is always the one which runs.

when I type:

```
scrapy crawl spider_a
```

spider_b is executed, same when I try:

```
scrapy crawl spider_b
```

spider_b is executed again, only way  I have handled to execute spider_a so far is by deleting the file which contains spider_b.

What can be causing this behavior?

Comment: Without examples of your code, in particular any class variables and init, no one can answer this.  If both spiders are their own classes, with a different `name` (eg. `name = 'spider_a'`), then Scrapy will run that spider.

Comment: As @Rejected mentioned above, you most likely have both under the same name: `name = 'spider_b'`.